# Capitalize all letters in a Textfield in Java

Tags: java, swing, text

Is it to possible to capitalize the letters in a Textfield as they are being typed by the user in Java?

E.g. The user would type 'hello' and 'HELLO' would appear in the Textfield.

(Odd request and I don't like the idea either).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Format JTextField's text to uppercase](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/FormatJTextFieldstexttouppercase.htm)

Uses `DocumentFilter`

**or**

[How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

Uses `MaskFormatter`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
jTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    char keyChar = e.getKeyChar();
    if (Character.isLowerCase(keyChar)) {
      e.setKeyChar(Character.toUpperCase(keyChar));
    }
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

`ModifyListener` and `getText().toUpperCase()` are your friends.

Comment: Make sure you test typing in the middle of the text.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an inefficient way to do it

but you could have a section in your KeyTyped event handler

```
if(event.getSource() == capitalTextArea) {
    String text = capitalTextArea.getText();
    if(Character.isLowerCase(text.charAt(text.length()-1))) {
        capitalTextArea.setText(text.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

I might have syntatical mistakes, but that's the apporach i'd take

Comment: I think you will have trouble with cursor positioning if you do this. It is also much less efficient than the DocumentFilter way.

Comment: You might be right about the cursor positioning. You're definitely right about there being more efficient ways to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
private void inText_UserIDKeyReleased( java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt ) {
    String UsrID=inText_UserID.getText().toUpperCase();
    inText_UserID.setText( UsrID );
}
```

Comment: no, you _never_ use keyListeners in Swing especially not if it effects the usability as badly as it does here ;-)

Answer (score -1):

A help for friends who find it interesting: how to make letters written in TextField capitalized. Ex: Legend:

`txtCadastrarNome` = name of the variable of text field.

`txtCadastrarNomeKeyTyped` = action when it is being typed from the keyboard.

```
private void txtCadastrarNomeKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) { 
txtCadastrarNome.setText(txtCadastrarNomeCliente.getText().toUpperCase());
}
```